# Disable auto-zoom when editing a shape in Visio

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

This is an annoyance more than an actual problem. Visio will automatically zoom in on a shape when I edit the text within. How do I disable this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Options > Advanced set `Automatically zoom text when editing under (number) points` to 0.

Comment: Thx so much. That's a really annoying feature.