# Visio 2016: Unable to Zoom when Editing Embedded Files (Excel spreadsheets)

Tags: microsoft-office, editing, zoom, microsoft-visio-2016

I am using Visio 2016 and having a constant, irritating issue. I need to edit embedded Excel spreadsheets everyday. Without fail, whenever I double-click the spreadsheet object in order to enter Edit mode for the spreadsheet, Visio zooms me OUT.

The text that was readable after using Ctrl+Shift+W is now half the size because I've been zoomed out by Visio. No matter what I do, I can't zoom in. Everything on the menus is greyed out, Ctrl+Shift+W does nothing, I am just stuck with a tiny spreadsheet on my monitor that I can barely read.  If I dare to use the one "zoom" button that is NOT greyed out--the button "100%", then by God, I am zoomed out so far that I get dark grey thumbnail-sized rectangle against the sea of Visio's background color.

How do I keep Visio from changing my Zoom level?? Why did Microsoft even thinking this was a good idea?

I've tried using the method described in this post: [Disable auto-zoom when editing a shape in Visio](https://superuser.com/questions/1064158/disable-auto-zoom-when-editing-a-shape-in-visio)

...but unfortunately it accomplished nothing and I am still automatically zoomed out from my document.

All help will be greatly appreciated.